# ¿Cómo exportar una lista de objetos a un archivo delimitado por punto y coma?

Tags: c#, linq

Resulta que tengo la necesidad de generar un archivo delimitado por puntos y comas desde una lista de objetos.

Esta seria mi clase:

```
 public class RipsUS
{
    public string TipoIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NumIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string CodEntAdm { get; set; }
    public int TipoUsuario { get; set; }
    public string PrimApeUsuario { get; set; }
    public string SegApeUsuario { get; set; }
    public string PrimNomUsuario { get; set; }
    public string SegNomUsuario { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public int UnidadMedidaEdad { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public string CodDepartamento { get; set; }
    public string CodMunicipio { get; set; }
    public string Zona { get; set; }

}
```

Creo una lista de los objetos de esta clase

```
List<RipsUS> listaRipsUs = new List<RipsUS>();
```

Ya tengo la lista con los datos cargados, pero ahora no sé cómo hacer para generar un archivo delimitado por punto y comas.

Comment: Por un lado hablas de punto y coma. Mas adelante dices coma solamente. ¿Cual es? ¿Y que pasa si uno de tus valores incluye un punto y coma? ¿Como lo manejas? ¿No preferirías usar algo mas estándar como el formato CSV?

Comment: Hola sstan, claro que podría utilizar el formato CSV pero es que tampoco se como hacer esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no te molesta usar el formato estándar CSV, puedes usar librerías ya existentes para manejar la lectura y escritura de tu estructura. De esta forma te evitas problemas en situaciones donde tus valores tienen un punto y coma, etc.

Un ejemplo de una libraría sencilla que puedes probar es [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) que puedes bajar por NuGet. Parece que varias personas lo usan. Eso es bueno, ya que indica que funciona bien, y probablemente ya se han corregido los defectos potenciales.

Usando tu clase `RipsUS`, aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo puedes escribir a un archivo y luego leerlo correctamente, aun cuando uses caracteres como `;` o `,`.

**Código:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var list = new List<RipsUS>();
    list.Add(new RipsUS { TipoIdUsuario = "zona", Edad = 56 });
    list.Add(new RipsUS { TipoIdUsuario = "ID", Edad = 100 });
    list.Add(new RipsUS { TipoIdUsuario = "ID,a;t\"hola;", Edad = 100 });

    // Test de escritura al archivo.
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"d:\test\test.csv"), Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(fileWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(list);
    }

    // Test de lectura del archivo.
    using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"d:\test\test.csv"), Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(fileReader))
    {
        foreach (var record in csvReader.GetRecords<RipsUS>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.TipoIdUsuario);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resultado en la consola:**

```
zona
ID
ID,a;t"hola;
```

**Contenido del archivo:**

```
TipoIdUsuario,NumIdUsuario,CodEntAdm,TipoUsuario,PrimApeUsuario,SegApeUsuario,PrimNomUsuario,SegNomUsuario,Edad,UnidadMedidaEdad,Sexo,CodDepartamento,CodMunicipio,Zona
zona,,,0,,,,,56,0,,,,
ID,,,0,,,,,100,0,,,,
"ID,a;t""hola;",,,0,,,,,100,0,,,,
```

Answer (score 3):

Como alternativa a la respuesta de @lois6b, puedes utilizar [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173183.aspx) para generar el archivo CSV, algo asi:

```
public void ACsv(string pathFichero)
{
    StringBuilder lineas = new StringBuilder();

    FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(RipsUS).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    bool newline = true;

    foreach (object o in listaRipsUs)
    {
        foreach (var f in fields)
        {
            if (newline)
                newline = !newline;
            else
                lineas.Append(";");

            var x = f.GetValue(o);

            if (x != null)
                lineas.Append(x.ToString());
        }
        lineas.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        newline = true;
    }

    File.WriteAllText(pathFichero, lineas.ToString());
}
```

El uso sería simplemente:

```
ACsv(@"c:\temp\archivo.csv");
```

Esto podria convertirse en un método de extensión generico, de tal manera que se podria utilizar para cualquier clase.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un `StringBuilder` e ir poniendo ahi la información separada por comas, después, guardarlo como fichero:

```
var csv = new StringBuilder();

//loop

    var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},.....", tipoIdUsuario, numIdUsuario,.... );
    csv.AppendLine(newLine);  

//fin loop

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
```