# ¿Cómo creo una lista de lista<objetos>?

Tags: c#

Tengo unas clases y unas listas de objetos de estas clases. Ejemplo de un par de esas clases:

```
public class RipsAC
{
    public string NumFactura { get; set; }
    public string CodigoPrestador { get; set; }
    public string TipoIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string NumIdUsuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaConsulta { get; set; }
}

public class RipsAH
{
    public string DxComplicacion { get; set; }
    public int EstadoSalida { get; set; }
    public string DxCausaBasicaMuerte { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaEgresoInstitucion { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan HoraEgresoInstitucion { get; set; }
}
```

Lleno unas listas de objetos de estas clases.

```
List<RipsAC> listaRipsAc = new List<RipsAC>();
List<RipsAH> listaRipsAh = new List<RipsAH>();
```

Ahora el problema es que deseo poder enviar estas listas a un método común usando un parámetro. Pero no sé de qué tipo sería el parámetro que debo agregar en el método.

```
public void ImprimirConsolidados(/*lista_Imprimir*/)
{
    string archivoRipsUs = @"C:\TMP\Rips\US_" +
                                            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmm") + ".csv";
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\TMP\Rips"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\TMP\Rips");
    }
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(archivoRipsUs), Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(fileWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(lista_Imprimir);
    }
}
```

¿Puedo agrupar estas listas en algún contenedor y poder enviarlas como un solo parámetro?

Comment: `public void ImprimirConsolidados(List<Object> param)
{}`

Comment: Por favor agrega detalles en cuanto a qué vas a hacer en el método `ImprimirConsolidados`. No es posible sugerirte el tipo adecuado para el (o los) parámetro(s) sin entender cómo funciona ese método y de qué manera piensas manejar listas de tipos distintos usando un mismo código.

Comment: creo que ese tipo de conversión no se puede hacer @Dev. Joel

Comment: @jeissoni22 añadí una respuesta para esto. si se puede realizar este tipo de conversión.

Comment: les quiero compartir un vídeo donde explica múltiples objetos en una vista o varios modelos en una vista con mvc5 asp.net link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsUWnheMOos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define que reciba las listas con su tipo de objeto:

```
public void ImprimirConsolidados(List<RipsAC> listaAc, List<RipsAH> listaAh)
{

}
```

De esta forma puedes llamar el método con las listas que creaste previamente:

```
ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAc, listaRipsAh);
```

---

También podrías definir recibir un tipo de lista Generica:

```
 public void ImprimirConsolidados(List<T> listaA, List<T> listaB)
    {

    }
```

---

En base a la actualización de tu pregunta  puedes convertir el Listado a uno generico List por medio de `.Cast<Object>().ToList()`

```
ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAc.Cast<Object>().ToList());
```

o

```
ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAh.Cast<Object>().ToList());
```

y tu método sería:

```
public ImprimirConsolidados(List<Object> myList)
{
    string archivoRipsUs = @"C:\TMP\Rips\US_" +
                                            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmm") + ".csv";
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\TMP\Rips"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\TMP\Rips");
    }
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(archivoRipsUs), Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(fileWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(lista_Imprimir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por su ayuda, pero digamos que si fueran muchas mas listas, no solo dos, es la única manera, no puedo agrupar estas listas en algún contenedor y poder enviarlas como un solo parámetro?

Comment: @jeissoni22 Si creas una clase extendica EntityExtend que herede de las clases que necesitas y trabajas con esta clase.

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta es sí, solo tienes que hacer unos pequeños cambios recibiendo un tipo genérico en el método `ImprimirConsolidados<T>(List<T> lista_Imprimir)` para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
public void ImprimirConsolidados<T>(List<T> lista_Imprimir)
{
    string archivoRipsUs = @"C:\TMP\Rips\US_" +
                                            DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmm") + ".csv";
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\TMP\Rips"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\TMP\Rips");
    }
    using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(archivoRipsUs), Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(fileWriter))
    {
        csvWriter.WriteRecords(lista_Imprimir);
    }
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Cabe mencionar que ahora para invocar al método es de la siguiente forma:

```
ImprimirConsolidados<List<RipsAC>>(listaRipsAc);
```

o en su caso

```
ImprimirConsolidados<List<RipsAH>>(listaRipsAh);
```

Comment: La llamada debería funcionar bien sin la parte `<List<RipsAH>>`. El compilador C# tiene la inteligencia para deducir el tipo exacto `T` según el tipo del parámetro. `ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAc);` es suficiente.

Answer (score 4):

El tipo de conversión *(cast)* si se puede realizar. para poder guardar cualquier tipo de Objetos.

```
List<RipsAC> listaRipsAc = new List<RipsAC>();
List<RipsAH> listaRipsAh = new List<RipsAH>();
ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAc.Cast<Object>().ToList());
```

Y su método para Guardar los datos en un archivo csv sería

```
public static void ImprimirConsolidados(List<Object> param)
  {
        string archivoRipsUs = @"C:\TMP\Rips\US_" +
                                                DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmm") + ".csv";
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\TMP\Rips"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\TMP\Rips");
        }
        using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(archivoRipsUs), Encoding.UTF8))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(fileWriter))
        {
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(param);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Siendo que la lista solo la usas para escribirla a una archivo CSV usando la sentencia siguiente:

```
csvWriter.WriteRecords(lista_Imprimir);
```

... y dado que `WriteRecords()` acepta un parámetro de tipo [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) (reconozco el uso de la librería [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) debido a tu anterior [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35060/c%C3%B3mo-exportar-una-lista-de-objetos-a-un-archivo-delimitado-por-punto-y-coma)), entonces, en este caso, puedes usar ese mismo tipo como parámetro para tu método:

```
public void ImprimirConsolidados(System.Collections.IEnumerable lista_Imprimir)
{
    // ...
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(lista_Imprimir);
    // ...
}
```

Haciéndolo de esta forma, puedes pasar las listas al método sin ningún tipo de cast:

```
List<RipsAC> listaRipsAc = new List<RipsAC>();
List<RipsAH> listaRipsAh = new List<RipsAH>();

ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAc);
ImprimirConsolidados(listaRipsAh);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, esta librería apenas la estoy conociendo. El namespace seria Collections, por si acaso.

Comment: Gracias. Corregí la `S` que me faltaba.